# Accessing CSS variable in React.js results in extra whitespace while in development but not in production

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, create-react-app

In my Create React App, I have a component where I'm accessing a CSS variable with `window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--color-red')`

And I noticed during development (react-scripts start) I get:

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--color-red') // " #ff0000"
```

While when during production (react-scripts build) I get:

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--color-red') // "#ff0000"
```

---

The CSS variable is declared in my main Sass file "App.scss":

```css
:root {
  --color-pj-red: #ff0000;
}
```

---

Why is this? The leading space seems unwanted. Most annoying though is that the value differs depending on the environment.

Comment: Don't think there's enough here to guess why it's happening. May want to include the code where that variable is defined.

Comment: @Yatrix Ok I made an edit but there really isn't anything special to it :p

Comment: Sure isn't. Hrm...The obvious workaround is trimming the spaces. As far as cause, I have no idea, sorry. Maybe try putting that into a .css file instead of a sass file and see if it behaves any differently. Wondering if the sass processing is doing something wacky there.

Comment: I read elsewhere that white-space is considered significant for custom CSS property values, but the minimization process for the production CSS doesn't seem to care about that and simply removes the spaces. That's why you're getting different values.

Comment: Can confirm this is also the case without React in plain JS and CSS